# New UDID to provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

If we add new UDID to a ad-hoc provisioning profile is it required to send new build to the updated device or is it enough if we install new ad-hoc provisioning profile in the device?

Answer (score 3):

yes you have to build your app with new provisioning profile then send a new update to the new device, and also you have to install new provisioning profile to the new device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need to install new provisioning profile and make build from source code using new provisioning profile.